# Proving there is an $n\times n$ symmetric matrix satisfying $\langle x,y \rangle = [x]_B^TA[y]_B$

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products

Let $V$ be a ﬁnite dimensional inner product space with basis $B$ = {$v_1, v_2,..., v_n$} Then there exists a symmetric $n\times n$ matrix $A$ such that for all vectors $x,y∈V$.

$\langle x,y \rangle = [x]_B^TA[y]_B$

Prove this for the case $n=2$.

I believe I know what the question is asking, and I know what all of the terms mean in the problem. But I'm not sure how to start the proof at all.

Comment: One approach is to look at $\langle x,y\rangle$ as a function of $y$ for fixed $x$.

Comment: Hint: Are there any particular vectors $x$, $y$ for which the coordinate vectors $[x]_{B}$ and $y_{B}$ are particularly nice? If so, what does your equation assert for these vectors? (On a tangent, `\langle` and `\rangle` give angle brackets $\langle\ ,\ \rangle$ with appropriate spacing; `<` and `>` are binary operators.)

Comment: Use \times for $\times$, i.e. n\times n for $n\times n$.

Answer (score 1):

I'll do it for $n=2$ as requested, but it generalizes quite easily. I'm also going to assume that your vector space is real, or at least that your inner product is symmetric and not conjugate symmetric.

Let $x=\alpha_1v_1+\alpha_2v_2$ and $y=\beta_1v_1+\beta_2v_2$. Then $\langle x,y\rangle=\langle \alpha_1v_1+\alpha_2v_2,\beta_1v_1+\beta_2v_2\rangle=\alpha_1\beta_1\langle v_1,v_1\rangle +\alpha_1\beta_2\langle v_1,v_2\rangle+\alpha_2\beta_1\langle v_2,v_1\rangle+\alpha_2\beta_2\langle v_2,v_2\rangle$.

What this shows is us that the value of the inner product is a function of the inner products of the basis vectors with each other.

Now if we let $a_{ij}=\langle v_i,v_j\rangle$ and call the matrix composed of these values $A$, it's not hard to verify via matrix multiplication that $[x]_b^TA[y]_b=\langle x,y\rangle$.