# $\langle u,v\rangle = [u]^T_B A_B[v]_B$ definition

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, vector-spaces, inner-products, linear-transformations

My textbooks says: An inner product $\langle u,v\rangle = [u]^T_B A_B[v]_B$ with bases $B = \langle b_1, b_2\rangle$

So does it work for all $u,v ∈ V$?

I don't see any proof or further explanation on the textbook, so how can I prove this definition?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: It is a definition, not a theorem.

Comment: I've taken the liberty to correct the notation for scalar product, which can be written with \rangle u,v \rangle

Comment: @EmilioNovati, it can be a theorem.

Comment: Possível duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1552531/proving-there-is-an-n-times-n-symmetric-matrix-satisfying-langle-x-y-rangle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is probably this:

Write $u = u_1 b_ 1 + u_2 b_ 2$ and $v = v_1 b_ 1 + v_2 b_ 2$.

Then, by bilinearity of $\langle \cdot , \cdot \rangle$, we have
$$
\langle u,v \rangle
= u_1 v_1 \langle b_1, b_1 \rangle
+ u_1 v_2 \langle b_1, b_2 \rangle
+ u_2 v_1 \langle b_2, b_1 \rangle
+ u_2 v_2 \langle b_2, b_2 \rangle
$$
which can be written in matrix form as
$$
\langle u,v \rangle
= \pmatrix{ u_1 & u_2}
\pmatrix{ \langle b_1, b_1 \rangle & \langle b_1, b_2 \rangle \\ \langle b_2, b_1 \rangle & \langle b_2, b_2 \rangle}
 \pmatrix{ v_1 \\ v_2}
$$
The matrix is called the [Gramian matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gramian_matrix) of the given inner product.